# Problema con AlertDialog y multichoice

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alertdialog

Tengo un AlertDialog que tiene un multichoice y ese lo lleno por medio de un arraylist de objetos, esos datos los obtengo desde un webservices.

El problema que tengo con este AlertDialog es que cuando doy click en mi actionbar para que se visualize si me carga los datos correctos, pero cuando trato de dar un tap al check que necesito, no me selecciona nada y me cierra el alertDialog y no me manda error en el logcat.

Aclaro el AlertDialog lo creo en el OnpostExecute ya que estoy usando Asyntask

Dejo código

Clase Asyntask, donde genero mi alertDialog

```
private class AsyncZona extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList>
    {
        private String ONControlWSURL;
        public AsyncZona(String ONControlWSURL)
        {
            this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
            ZonaArrayList = new ArrayList<Zona>();
            webService O_WS = new webService(ONControlWSURL);
            ZonaArrayList=O_WS.Zona();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);


            final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
            //zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
            for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
                //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
                zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
                // zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getClave();
            }
             final boolean[] isSelectedArray ={false,false,false,false,false,false};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
                builder.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona(s) que Visitaras");
                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(zona, isSelectedArray, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccionado" + zona[which],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //do something
                    }
                });;
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Solucion les dejo el codigo

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

            final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
            // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
            for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
                //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
                zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
                // zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getClave();
            }
            final boolean[] selCrayons={true,false,true};
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Selecciona la(s) Zonas a Visitar");
            dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona,selCrayons,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg2) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zona Seleccionada " + zona[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya quedo soluciones les dejo el codigo...

Comment: Pero pon la pregunta con el problema y agrega la solución como respuesta! :P

Comment: La solución que encontraste ponla como respuesta a tu propia pregunta y cierra la pregunta como resuelta.

Comment: Elenasys estas??